# How to concatenate files from a directory following order of the files in R

Tags: r, csv, concatenation, rbind

I want to concatenate all files (.csv) in a directory using R. I have 2 codes that work nice, but their problem is that they do not concatenate them following the order they have in the directory. Any suggestion would be welcome !

The files are named "res_i.ihs_ihs_scores.csv", where the "i" from "res_i" goes between 1 and 22.

Code 1:

```
setwd("/Users/lucas/Desktop/results/iHS/files")
file_list <- list.files()
dataset <- do.call("rbind",lapply(file_list,
                  FUN=function(files){read.table(files,
                  header=TRUE, sep=",")}))
```

Code 2:

```
setwd("/Users/lucas/Desktop/results/iHS/files")
library(plyr)
file_list <- list.files()
dataset <- ldply(file_list, read.table, header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Comment: Is the order of `file_list` correct?  If so then it should work fine.  Otherwise, sort that vector first.

Comment: No need to put `rbind` in quotes. No need to wrap the first call in `function` — just do the same as for the second code.

Comment: There are times when a good old fashioned `for` loop are perfectly acceptable. This seems like one of them. Iterate over `1:22` and `paste` the file name together.